# Sistema Algébrico - Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Olá,

Eu preciso fazer uma atividade para resolver sistemas triangulares inferiores de n incógnitas e n termos independentes.

**OBS: nenhuma das funções pode ter impressão dentro delas, e eu não posso usar o matrix ou a biblioteca numpy.**

É necessário fazer uma função em python que terá duas listas como argumento:

• a primeira lista tem (n (n + 1)) / 2 termos, que são os coeficientes que acompanham as incógnitas;

• a segunda lista contém os n termos independentes do sistema.

Esta função retornará uma lista com os n valores da incógnitas x.

Além disso, o programa também deve ter:

• uma função para exibir/imprimir o sistema (conforme mostrado abaixo), e abaixo as incógnitas x e seus valores calculados pela outra função.

[image: Imagem que mostra como o sistema deve ser impresso]

O código que eu tentei foi:

```
lista_1 = [] #Insira a lista de coeficientes
lista_2 = [] #Insira a lista de termos independentes
tamanho_l1 = len(lista_1)
tamanho_l2 = len(lista_2)
    
def solução(lista_1,lista_2):
    lista_3 = []
    if lista_1[0] == 0 and lista_2[0] == 0:
        return ("Sistema possível e indeterminado")
    elif lista_1[0] == 0 and lista_2[0] != 0:
        return ("Sistema impossível")
    else: 
        lista_3 = lista_3 + [lista_2[0]/lista_1[0]]
        for i in range(1, tamanho_l2): 
            soma = 0
            for j in range(0, i):
                soma = lista_1[i]*lista_3[j] + soma
            if lista_1[i] == 0 and lista_2[i] - soma == 0:
                return ("Sistema possível e indeterminado")
            elif lista_1[i] == 0 and lista_2[i] - soma != 0:
                return ("Sistema impossível")
            else: 
                lista_3 = lista_3 + [(lista_2[i] - soma)/lista_1[i]]
    return lista_3
 

print (solução(lista_1,lista_2)) 
print ('\n')
n = 1   
m = 1 
z = 2    
for i in range (tamanho_l2):
    v = 1
    if i == 0:
        print (f'{lista_1[i]: >6.2f}*x{v}', end = ' ')
        print (f'= {lista_2[i]: >30.2f} \n')
        n = n + 1
    elif i == 1:
        for j in range (i, 3):
            if j == 2:
                print (f'{lista_1[j]: >6.2f}*x{v}', end = ' ')
            else:
                print (f'{lista_1[j]: >6.2f}*x{v} +', end = ' ')
            v = v + 1
        n = n + 1
        print (f'= {lista_2[i]: >18.2f} \n')
    else: 
        v = 1
        for j in range(i + m, i + m + n):    
            if j == (i + m + n - 1):
                print (f'{lista_1[j]: >6.2f}*x{v}', end = ' ')
            else:
                print (f'{lista_1[j]: >6.2f}*x{v} +', end = ' ')
            v = v + 1
        n = n + 1  
        print (f'= {lista_2[i]: >6.2f} \n')
        m = m + z
        z = z + 1
```

No meu código:

• A função para resolver o sistema não funcionou

Por exemplo, usando estas 2 listas:

[-13, 13, 3, -5, -1, -1, 3, 0, 1, 1] (coeficientes)

[-13, 13, -7, 4] (termos independentes)

a resposta deveria ser [1, 0, 2, -1], mas a saída é [1,0, 0,0, -3,3333333333333335, 1,5333333333333337]

• Não consegui executar a última função (que começa depois de "imprimir ('\ n')") sem usar print.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Vc poderia mostrar como das listas de coeficientes e termos independentes, vc chegaria ao resultado de `[1, 0, 2, 2]`, não seria `[1, 0, 2, -1]`?

Comment: Me desculpa, a resposta seria [1, 0, 2, -1]. Vou alterar a questão.

Comment: Você sabe como eu posso fazer a última função sem usar print? Eu tentei definir uma função `def impressão (lista_1, lista_2) `, adicionando a variável `impressão = ''`. Depois onde tem print, como por exemplo nessa linha `print (f'{lista_1[i]: >6.2f}*x{v}', end = ' ')`, eu troquei por `impressão += f'{lista_1[i]: >6.2f}*x{v}'`. No final da função coloquei `return impressão`, e fora da função, `print (impressão (lista_1, lista_2))`. No entanto, não ocorre nenhuma impressão.  @PauloMarques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, uma abordagem para resolver esse problema é pensar com classes, objetos e métodos. Você tem um objeto, que é uma matriz. Essa matriz pode ter métodos para se obter um valor, alterar um valor, obter a largura, a altura, somar uma linha com um conjunto de valores ou multiplicar uma linha por um valor, dentre outras possibilidades. Finalmente, há um método estático que pode construir uma matriz triangular inferior a partir dos valores dados e outro (não-estático) que pode realizar o método de eliminação de Gauss que é o que você está fazendo.

Ou seja:

```py
# Autor - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132
class Matriz:
    def __init__(self, largura, altura, valores):
        if len(valores) != altura:
            raise IndexError("O conjunto de valores não tem o tamanho correto.")
        for linha in valores:
            if len(linha) != largura:
                raise IndexError("O conjunto de valores não tem o tamanho correto.")
        self.__valores = valores

    @property
    def largura(self):
        return len(self.__valores[0])

    @property
    def altura(self):
        return len(self.__valores)

    def valor(self, num_linha, num_coluna):
        if num_linha < 0 or num_linha >= self.altura or num_coluna < 0 or num_coluna >= self.largura:
            raise IndexError(f"Não há posição a_{num_linha}_{num_coluna}.")
        return self.__valores[num_linha][num_coluna]

    def definir(self, num_linha, num_coluna, valor):
        if num_linha < 0 or num_linha >= self.altura or num_coluna < 0 or num_coluna >= self.largura:
            raise IndexError(f"Não há posição a_{num_linha}_{num_coluna}.")
        self.__valores[num_linha][num_coluna] = valor

    def multiplicar_linha(self, num_linha, valor):
        if num_linha < 0 or num_linha >= self.altura:
            raise IndexError(f"Não há linha {num_linha}.")
        for coluna in range(0, self.largura):
            self.__valores[num_linha][coluna] *= valor

    def somar_linha(self, num_linha, valores, multiplicador):
        if num_linha < 0 or num_linha >= self.altura:
            raise IndexError(f"Não há linha {num_linha}.")
        if len(valores) != self.largura:
            raise IndexError("O conjunto de valores não tem o tamanho correto.")
        for coluna in range(0, self.largura):
            self.__valores[num_linha][coluna] += valores[coluna] * multiplicador

    def linha(self, num_linha):
        if num_linha < 0 or num_linha >= self.altura:
            raise IndexError(f"Não há linha {num_linha}.")
        return self.__valores[num_linha]

    @staticmethod
    def triangular_inferior(lista_1, lista_2):
        t = len(lista_2)
        if t * (t + 1) / 2 != len(lista_1):
            raise IndexError("A segunda lista não tem a quantidade correta de termos.")
        matriz = []
        n = 0
        for i in range(0, t):
            linha = []
            for j in range(0, i + 1):
                linha.append(lista_1[n])
                n += 1
            for j in range(i + 1, t):
                linha.append(0)
            matriz.append(linha)
            linha.append(lista_2[i])
        return Matriz(t + 1, t, matriz)

    def eliminacao_gauss(self):
        for i in range(0, self.altura):
            if self.__valores[i][i] == 0:
                raise IndexError("Zero na coluna principal.")
        for i in range(0, self.altura):
            self.multiplicar_linha(i, 1 / self.__valores[i][i])
            for j in range(i + 1, self.altura):
                self.somar_linha(j, self.__valores[i], -self.__valores[j][i])
        ret = []
        for i in range(0, self.altura):
            ret.append(self.__valores[i][-1])
        return ret

    def __str__(self):
        t = ""
        for i in range(0, self.altura):
            for j in range(0, self.largura):
                v = self.__valores[i][j]
                if j == self.largura - 1:
                    t += f" = {v: >6.2f}"
                else:
                    if j != 0: t += " "
                    if v == 0:
                        t += " " * (12 + len(str(j + 1)))
                    else:
                        s = "+" if v > 0 else "-"
                        t += f"{s} {abs(v): >6.2f} * x{j + 1}"
            t += "\n"
        return t

def mostra_vetor(vetor):
    aux = ""
    for i in range(0, len(vetor)):
        aux += f"{vetor[i]} * x{i + 1}\n"
    return aux

m = Matriz.triangular_inferior([-13, 13, 3, -5, -1, -1, 3, 0, 1, 1], [-13, 13, -7, 4])
print(m)
resultado = m.eliminacao_gauss()
print(resultado)
print(mostra_vetor(resultado))
```

Essa solução permite que você possa adicionar outros métodos na matriz para fazer outras coisas. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/MkxAxK)

Se você preferir juntar apenas as partes necessárias em um procedimento só, o resultado seria esse:

```py
# Autor - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132
def solucao_triangular_inferior(lista_1, lista_2):
    # Descobre a altura e a largura e verifica se as listas tem o tamanho certo.
    altura = len(lista_2)
    largura = altura + 1
    if altura * (altura + 1) / 2 != len(lista_1):
        raise IndexError("A segunda lista não tem a quantidade correta de termos.")

    # Constrói a matriz a partir das listas. A última coluna serão os valores de lista_2.
    matriz = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(0, altura):
        linha = []
        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            linha.append(lista_1[n])
            n += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, altura):
            linha.append(0)
        matriz.append(linha)
        linha.append(lista_2[i])

    # Cria uma segunda matriz como cópia da primeira, pois a primeira será destruída como parte do processo de eliminação de Gauss.
    copia = []
    for linha in matriz:
        copia.append(linha[:])

    # Verifica se não há nenhum zero na diagonal principal.
    for i in range(0, altura):
        if matriz[i][i] == 0:
            raise IndexError("Zero na coluna principal.")

    # Zera os coeficientes fora da diagonal principal.
    for i in range(0, altura):
        # Reduz o coeficiente da diagonal principal para 1 e todos os outros da mesma linha na mesma proporção.
        valor = 1 / matriz[i][i]
        for coluna in range(0, largura):
            matriz[i][coluna] *= valor

        # Corrige as demais linhas abaixo.
        for j in range(i + 1, altura):
            # Conceitualmente, o certo seria percorrer todas as colunas da linha j.
            # No entanto, todas as colunas diferentes da coluna i e da última teriam seus valores inalterados,
            # e portanto só precisamos mexer nessas duas colunas.
            matriz[j][-1] -= matriz[i][-1] * matriz[j][i]
            matriz[j][i] = 0

    # Monta o resultado final.
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, altura):
        ret.append(matriz[i][-1])

    # Retorna a matriz original e o resultado.
    return copia, ret

def mostra_matriz(matriz):
    altura = len(matriz)
    largura = len(matriz[0])
    t = ""
    for i in range(0, altura):
        for j in range(0, largura):
            v = matriz[i][j]
            if j == largura - 1:
                t += f" = {v: >6.2f}"
            else:
                if j != 0: t += " "
                if v == 0:
                    t += " " * (12 + len(str(j + 1)))
                else:
                    s = "+" if v > 0 else "-"
                    t += f"{s} {abs(v): >6.2f} * x{j + 1}"
        t += "\n"
    return t

def mostra_vetor(vetor):
    aux = ""
    for i in range(0, len(vetor)):
        aux += f"{vetor[i]} * x{i + 1}\n"
    return aux

matriz, resultado = solucao_triangular_inferior([-13, 13, 3, -5, -1, -1, 3, 0, 1, 1], [-13, 13, -7, 4])
print(mostra_matriz(matriz))
print(mostra_vetor(resultado))
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/lLemJS)

Comment: Obrigada! @Victor Stafusa

Comment: No meu código eu tinha feito a verificação:  `if (lista_1 != [] or lista_2 != []) and (tamanho_l1 == ((tamanho_l2*(tamanho_l2 + 1)) / 2)) and ((all(isinstance(n, float) for n in lista_1) or (all(isinstance(n, int) for n in lista_1))) or (all(isinstance(n, float) for n in lista_2) or all(isinstance(n, int) for n in lista_2))): return True else:  return False`. em que `tamanho_l2 = len(lista_2)` e `tamanho_l1 = len(lista_1)`

Comment: Você pode me ajudar com a impressão do sistema como na imagem sem usar print?

Comment: Você sabe como eu posso fazer a última função sem usar print? Eu tentei definir uma função `def impressão (lista_1, lista_2)` , adicionando a variável `impressão = ''`. Depois onde tem print, como por exemplo nessa linha `print (f'{lista_1[i]: >6.2f}*x{v}', end = ' ')`, eu troquei por `impressão += f'{lista_1[i]: >6.2f}*x{v}'`. No final da função coloquei return impressão, e fora da função, `print (impressão (lista_1, lista_2))`. No entanto, não ocorre nenhuma impressão

Comment: @None O seu problema com esses `print`s é mostrar a matriz original na tela?

Comment: É porque eu não posso usar print dentro da função, do jeito que eu fiz a impressão sai correta, mas eu teria que ajustar para transformar isso numa função sem print, igual a outra.

Comment: Na verdade tem que mostrar o sistema linear, igual na imagem, em que a lista 1 acompanha as incógnitas e tem = termo independente. No caso das listas dos exemplo, teria que sair algo assim:                 
`-13.00*x1 =  -13.00 

 13.00*x1 +   3.00*x2 = 13.00 

 -5.00*x1 +  -1.00*x2 +  -1.00*x3 =  -7.00 

  3.00*x1 +   0.00*x2 +   1.00*x3 +   1.00*x4 =  4.00`

 Cada um em uma linha, no meu código, essa impressão consegue ser realizada, mas não consegui refazer o código sem usar print. Tentei fazer igual expliquei no 3º comentário acima desse. @Victor

Comment: @None Editei a resposta. Agora está ok?

Comment: Tudo bem. Obrigada! Desse jeito eu consigo refazer a parte da impressão do sistema sem usar print.

Comment: @None Editei outra vez, mas só o primeiro código. Serve?

Comment: Eu entendi melhor o 2º código, vou tentar fazer por ele. Mas vou tentar fazer a impressão do sistema parecido com esse `def mostra_vetor(vetor):`. Obrigada. @VictorStafusa

Comment: @None Editei também o segundo código.

Comment: @None Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.

Answer (score 0):

Caro,

Embora a solução abaixo não tenha nenhum teste, veja se te ajuda na solução do problema.

Comentei o código, pois achei melhor que fazer um parágrafo descrevendo o que ele faz.

```
coeficientes = [-13, 13, 3, -5, -1, -1, 3, 0, 1, 1]
termos_independentes = [-13, 13, -7, 4]

lista_x = []

# Onde o `slice` de coeficientes começará.
idx = 0

for termo in termos_independentes:
    # qtd - quantos elementos da lista serão usados. Número de `x` já encontrados + 1
    qtd = len(lista_x) + 1

    # slice - pedaço de coeficientes que será usado 
    slice = coeficientes[idx: idx + qtd]

    # inicializando soma
    soma = 0

    # loop que fará a soma considerando os `x` já encontrados e o slice
    for i, x in enumerate(lista_x):
        soma = soma + (slice[i] * x)

    # o último termo do `slice` não foi usado, é para ele que o novo `x` tem que ser calculado
    res = (termo - soma) / slice[-1]

    # inclui `x` na lista
    lista_x.append(res)

    # atualiza o `idx`, ou seja, a partir de onde o próximo slice começará
    idx = idx + qtd

print(lista_x)
[1.0, 0.0, 2.0, -1.0]
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida no código, favor comentar que eu atualizo o post com maiores detalhes.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigada! @PauloMarques

Answer (score 0):

> **Atenção:** Esse algoritmo não faz nenhum tipo de verificação ou tratamento de erros.

```
linhas = int(input('Qual o número de equações no sistema: '))

a = [[0] * linhas for l in range(linhas)]    #inicializa a lista de coeficientes. 

#Inicializa a coleta de dados...
for l in range(linhas):
  linha = input(f'Digite todos os coeficientes da linha {l + 1} separados por espaço:\n')
  for c, val in enumerate(str.split(linha,' ')):
    a[l][c] = float(val)

termos = input(f'Digite todos os termos independentes separados por espaço:\n')
b = [float(t) for t in str.split(termos,' ')]
#...finalizada a coleta de dados.

x = [0 for l in range(linhas)]    #Unicializa a lista de soluções.    
x[0]= b[0] / a[0][0]              #Calcula  x₁

#A partir de x₂ ...
for i in range(1, linhas):
  #usa a formula para calcular xₗ
  x[i] = (b[i] - sum([a[i][j] * x[j] for j in range(0, i)])) / a[i][i]  

print(f'solução: {x}')
```

<sup>teste o código no [repli.it](https://repl.it/repls/ConfusedSolidHexagons)</sup>

Exemplo:

```
Qual o número de equações no sistema: 3
Digite todos os coeficientes da linha 1 separados por espaço:
2
Digite todos os coeficientes da linha 2 separados por espaço:
1 -9
Digite todos os coeficientes da linha 3 separados por espaço:
6 5 9
Digite todos os termos independentes separados por espaço:
10 2 70
solução: [5.0, 0.3333333333333333, 4.259259259259259]
```